# List only local SmartCard readers

Tags: winapi, smartcard, winscard

I've been struggling to find a way for listing only locally available SmartCard readers. Or at least differentiate between local readers and readers shared via RDP session.

I'm using `SCardListReaders`, but that lists all readers registered into the SmartCard subsystem, including readers from RDP shares. Are there any way to filter that list?

One way would be to list physical reader devices with  `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, then use `SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId`. But i need to have Windows 7 support and `SCardListReadersWithDeviceInstanceId` was introduced from Windows 8.

Any alternative solution is also appreciated.

Comment: Match SmartCard with Setup is a direction. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798497/11128312).

Comment: I'm aware of that question, but i couldn't match the names from the smart card subsystem against the information gathered from SetupAPI. It seems from the comments they couldn't do it either (at least with 100% precision).
I might do an another trial with that code again as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` constant for `dwScope` parameter when calling [`SCardEstablishContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardestablishcontext)

Remote SmartCard readers can only exists inside of user context.

Comment: I've tested this between two Win10 machines and `SCardListReaders` still lists the remote reader.

Comment: Try to launch your application not from user context. Any service running as `Local Service` or `Network Service`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible, it's a desktop application not a service.